# Navigating a bounded 2D list (Advent of Code, Day 2: "Bathroom Security")

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, f#

I'm trying to solve the following [Advent of Code problem](https://adventofcode.com/2016/day/2) in F# for practice.

**Description of problem (can be found [here](https://adventofcode.com/2016/day/2)):**

Basically, there's a 'key pad' that I need to figure the combination to. To do that, I have to follow instructions in the form 'U'/'D'/'L'/'R' to move a key up, down, left, or right in a gird of keys (see `puzzleInput` below). A newline means to take down the number I'm currently on and record it. I am bounded to the grid (eg. if I'm on the upper edge I can't move any more if the instruction was 'U'). The challenge is in 2 parts, in the first part the keypad is a 3x3 numerical grid (1..9). In the second part the keypad is a diamond shaped 5x5 alphanumeric grid (1..9, A, B, C, D) - movement is constrained to the diamond shape.

**My attempt:**

```
open System
open System.IO

// possible instructions, halt means to 'take down current number'
type Instruction = 
  | Up
  | Down
  | Right
  | Left
  | Halt

// helper method used later
let getLastElementOf seq = 
  seq |> List.rev |> List.head  

// method to get code, see sample input below
let GetCode rawInput keyPadButtons startPos = 

  let parse (rawInput:string) :List<Instruction> = 
    rawInput.ToCharArray()
    |> Seq.map (function 
                | 'U' -> Up
                | 'D' -> Down
                | 'R' -> Right
                | 'L' -> Left
                | '\n' -> Halt
                | _ -> failwith "Unexpected token.")
    |> (fun x ->  Seq.toList x @ [Halt])

  // used to enforce grid bounds, method used by followOne
  let validate pos fallbackPos (tdarr:List<List<char>>)  = 
    try 
      if tdarr.[fst pos].[snd pos] <> ' '  //I'm using ' ' as a padding 
      then pos
      else fallbackPos
    with
    | e -> fallbackPos

  // follows one instruction, method used by followAll
  let followOne (grid:List<List<char>>) (pos:int * int) (instruction:Instruction) :int * int =
    validate (match instruction with
              | Up -> fst pos - 1 , snd pos
              | Down -> fst pos + 1, snd pos
              | Right -> fst pos, snd pos + 1
              | Left -> fst pos, snd pos - 1
              | _ -> failwith "Unknown instructon.") pos grid

  // follow all instructions & produce result
  let followAll (keyPadButtons:List<List<char>>) (instructions:List<Instruction>) :string = 
    instructions
    |> Seq.mapFold (fun state instruction -> 
                    "", (
                         if instruction = Halt 
                         then fst state, 
                              snd state + keyPadButtons
                                          .[fst (getLastElementOf (fst state))]
                                          .[snd (getLastElementOf (fst state))].ToString()
                         else fst state
                              @[followOne keyPadButtons (getLastElementOf (fst state)) instruction], 
                              snd state
                        )
                    ) ([startPos], "")
    |> snd |> snd

  rawInput
  |> parse
  |> followAll keyPadButtons

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

  let puzzleInput = "DLUUULUDLRDDLLLUDULLULLRUURURLUULDUUUDLDDRUDLUULLRLDDURURDDRDRDLDURRURDLDUURULDDULDRDDLDLDLRDRUURLDLUDDDURULRLLLLRLULLUDRDLDUURDURULULULRLULLLULURLRDRDDDDDDDLRLULUULLULURLLDLRLUDULLDLLURUDDLDULDLULDDRLRLRDDLRURLLLURRLDURRDLLUUUUDRURUULRLDRRULLRUDLDRLUDRDRDRRDDURURRDRDRUDURDLUDRUDLRRULDLRDDRURDDUUDLDRDULDDRRURLLULRDRURLRLDLLLUULUUDLUDLDRRRRDUURULDUDUDRLDLLULLLRDDDDDLRDDLLUULLRRRDURLRURDURURLUDRRLRURDRDRRRRULUDLDRDULULRUDULLLUDRRLRLURDDURULDUUDULLURUULRDRDULRUUUDURURDDRRUDURRLRDRULRUUU
LDRURRUUUULDRDDDLLULDRUDDRLLDLDRDLRUDDDLDDULULULLRULDUDRRDLRUURURDRURURDLLRUURDUUDRLDURDRDLRRURURDUUUURUURRLLLDRDUURRRRURULUUUDLUDDRUURRLDULRDULRRRRUDURRLURULRURRDRDLLDRRDUDRDURLDDRURULDRURUDDURDLLLUURRLDRULLURDRDRLDRRURRLRRRDDDDLUDLUDLLDURDURRDUDDLUDLRULRRRDRDDLUDRDURDRDDUURDULRRULDLDLLUDRDDUDUULUDURDRLDURLRRDLDDLURUDRLDUURLLRLUDLLRLDDUDLLLRRRLDLUULLUDRUUDRLDUUUDUURLRDDDDRRDRLDDRDLUDRULDDDRDUULLUUUUULDULRLLLRLLDULRDUDDRDDLRRLRDDULLDURRRURDDUDUDDRLURRLUUUULLDRDULUUDRDULDLLUDLURDLLURRDLUULURRULRLURRRRRUURDDURLRLLDDLRRDUUURDRDUDRDDDLLDDRDRRRLURRDUULULULULRRURDDLDDLLLRUDDDDDDLLLRDULURULLRLRDRR
DDRLLLDLRRURRDLDDRUURRURRLRRRRUURUURDLURRRDDLRUDRURLUURLLRRLRLURLURURDULLLLDLRURULUUDURRLULRDRDRRDDLLULRLUDLUUUDRLLRRURRLDULDDLRRLUUUUDDLRLDRLRRDRDLDDURDDRDDLDLURLRRRDDUDLLRLRLURRRRULLULLLLDRLDULDLLDULRLDRDLDDRRDDDDRUDRLLURULRLDDLLRRURURDDRLLLULLULDDRDLDDDLRLLDRLDRUURRULURDDRLULLDUURRULURUUDULLRUDDRRLLDLLRDRUDDDDLLLDDDLLUUUULLDUUURULRUUDUUUDDLDURLDRDRRLLUDULDLUDRLLLDRRRULUUDDURUDRLUDDRRLLDUDUURDDRURLUURDURURURRUUDUDDLLLDRRRURURRURDLRULLDUDRLRLLRUDRUDLR
RRRDRLRURLRRLUURDRLDUURURLRDRRUDLLUUDURULLUURDLLDRRLURRUDUUDRRURLRRDULLDDLRRRUDUUDUUDLDDDLUUDLDULDDULLDUUUUDDUUDUDULLDDURRDLRRUDUDLRDUULDULRURRRLDLLURUDLDDDRRLRDURDLRRLLLRUDLUDRLLLRLLRRURUDLUDURLDRLRUDLRUULDRULLRLDRDRRLDDDURRRUDDDUDRRDRLDDRDRLLRLLRDLRDUDURURRLLULRDRLRDDRUULRDDRLULDLULURDLRUDRRDDDLDULULRDDRUDRLRDDRLDRDDRRRDUURDRLLDDUULRLLLULLDRDUDRRLUUURLDULUUURULLRLUDLDDLRRDLLRDDLRDRUUDURDDLLLDUUULUUDLULDUDULDRLRUDDURLDDRRRDLURRLLRRRUDDLDDRURDUULRUURDRRURURRRUUDUDULUDLUDLLLUUUULRLLRRRRDUDRRDRUDURLUDDLDRDLDDRULLRRULDURUL
DLLLRDDURDULRRLULURRDULDLUDLURDDURRLLRRLLULRDLDRDULRLLRDRUUULURRRLLRLDDDRDRRULDRRLLLLDLUULRRRURDDRULLULDDDLULRLRRRUDRURULUDDRULDUDRLDRRLURULRUULLLRUURDURLLULUURUULUUDLUDLRRULLLRRLRURDRRURDRULRURRUDUDDDRDDULDLURUDRDURLDLDLUDURLLRUULLURLDDDURDULRLUUUDLLRRLLUURRDUUDUUDUURURDRRRRRRRRRUDULDLULURUDUURDDULDUDDRDDRDRLRUUUUDLDLRDUURRLRUUDDDDURLRRULURDUUDLUUDUUURUUDRURDRDDDDULRLLRURLRLRDDLRUULLULULRRURURDDUULRDRRDRDLRDRRLDUDDULLDRUDDRRRD"

  let part1Code = GetCode puzzleInput [ [' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '];
                                        [' '; '1'; '2'; '3'; ' '];
                                        [' '; '4'; '5'; '6'; ' ']; 
                                        [' '; '7'; '8'; '9'; ' ']; 
                                        [' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '] ] (2, 2)

  let part2Code = GetCode puzzleInput [ [' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '];
                                        [' '; ' '; ' '; '1'; ' '; ' '; ' '];
                                        [' '; ' '; '2'; '3'; '4'; ' '; ' '];
                                        [' '; '5'; '6'; '7'; '8'; '9'; ' '];
                                        [' '; ' '; 'A'; 'B'; 'C'; ' '; ' '];
                                        [' '; ' '; ' '; 'D'; ' '; ' '; ' '];
                                        [' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' ']] (3, 1)

  printfn "Part 1: %A, Part 2: %A" part1Code part2Code
```

This code yields the correct answers required by the challenge. The problem is I think it is too verbose (I'm doing this to learn clean code) and honestly I think there must be a better way to do most things that I haven't considered. Feedback on how to shorten (DRY) this code and to make it more readable is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a late review I have the following comments:

```
 let getLastElementOf seq = seq |> List.rev |> List.head
```

What's wrong with `seq |> List.last`?

You use a lot of `fst` and `snd` to reach tuple values, instead you could do:

```
 let validate (x, y) fallbackPos (tdarr:List<List<char>>)  = 
try 
  if tdarr.[x].[y] <> ' '  //I'm using ' ' as a padding 
  then (x, y)
  else fallbackPos
with
| e -> fallbackPos
```

To me it is much cleaner.

IMO the type definition of Instructions do more damage than good resulting in an unnecessary double match in `parse` and `followOne`.

I think it's a good idea to extent the keypad and use it for validation of a step.

My solution would be something like below. The concept is to think of the keypad as a coordinate system and then convert the result point of each instruction sequence to a key in the pad:

```
module Program
open System

let squarePad = [[' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '];
                 [' '; '1'; '2'; '3'; ' '];
                 [' '; '4'; '5'; '6'; ' ']; 
                 [' '; '7'; '8'; '9'; ' ']; 
                 [' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '] ]

let diamondPad = [[' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '];
                  [' '; ' '; ' '; '1'; ' '; ' '; ' '];
                  [' '; ' '; '2'; '3'; '4'; ' '; ' '];
                  [' '; '5'; '6'; '7'; '8'; '9'; ' '];
                  [' '; ' '; 'A'; 'B'; 'C'; ' '; ' '];
                  [' '; ' '; ' '; 'D'; ' '; ' '; ' '];
                  [' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' '; ' ']]

let isValid (pad: char list list) = fun x y -> pad.[y].[x] <> ' '   // Checks if a field in the keypad has a value
let toKey (pad: char list list) = fun (x, y) -> pad.[y].[x]         // Converts a coordinate set to the key in the pad

// The main function for the pad walk
let doTheWalk (input: string) (pos: int * int) isValid toKey  = 
    // Move or hold according to the validation of the new position
    let move (x, y) instr = 
        let x1, y1 = match instr with
                     | 'L' -> x - 1, y
                     | 'R' -> x + 1, y
                     | 'U' -> x, y - 1
                     | 'D' -> x, y + 1
                     | _ -> x, y // Ignoring what ever invalid input
        match isValid x1 y1 with
        | true -> x1, y1
        | false -> x, y

    // Accumulating the resulting position through an instruction sequence 
    let parse pos instr = 
        let result = instr |> Seq.fold move pos
        result, result // The result of the move is both the current accumulated state and the current mapping result

    // The input is considered to be a string with line breaks defining each instruction sequence
    input.Split('\n') 
    |> Seq.mapFold (fun curPos instr -> instr |> parse curPos) pos // Maps each char in an instruction line to a new position with the "folded" position from the previous instruction as base
    |> fst // Use the sequence of points calculated in the mapFold above to...  
    |> Seq.mapFold(fun str pos -> str, sprintf "%s%c" str (toKey pos)) "" // ... convert to a key in the pad and finally concat them to a string
    |> snd // Returns the folded string with end key for each instruction line

// Starter function
let doMySolution input = 

    let squareResult = 
        doTheWalk 
            input (2, 2) 
            (isValid squarePad)
            (toKey squarePad)

    let diamondResult = 
        doTheWalk 
            input (3, 1) 
            (isValid diamondPad)
            (toKey diamondPad)

    printfn "Square: %A\tDiamond: %A" squareResult diamondResult

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let input = "ULL\nRRDDD\nLURDL\nUUUUD"
    let puzzleInput = "DLUUULUDLRDDLLLUDULLULLRUURURLUULDUUUDLDDRUDLUULLRLDDURURDDRDRDLDURRURDLDUURULDDULDRDDLDLDLRDRUURLDLUDDDURULRLLLLRLULLUDRDLDUURDURULULULRLULLLULURLRDRDDDDDDDLRLULUULLULURLLDLRLUDULLDLLURUDDLDULDLULDDRLRLRDDLRURLLLURRLDURRDLLUUUUDRURUULRLDRRULLRUDLDRLUDRDRDRRDDURURRDRDRUDURDLUDRUDLRRULDLRDDRURDDUUDLDRDULDDRRURLLULRDRURLRLDLLLUULUUDLUDLDRRRRDUURULDUDUDRLDLLULLLRDDDDDLRDDLLUULLRRRDURLRURDURURLUDRRLRURDRDRRRRULUDLDRDULULRUDULLLUDRRLRLURDDURULDUUDULLURUULRDRDULRUUUDURURDDRRUDURRLRDRULRUUU\n"
                    + "LDRURRUUUULDRDDDLLULDRUDDRLLDLDRDLRUDDDLDDULULULLRULDUDRRDLRUURURDRURURDLLRUURDUUDRLDURDRDLRRURURDUUUURUURRLLLDRDUURRRRURULUUUDLUDDRUURRLDULRDULRRRRUDURRLURULRURRDRDLLDRRDUDRDURLDDRURULDRURUDDURDLLLUURRLDRULLURDRDRLDRRURRLRRRDDDDLUDLUDLLDURDURRDUDDLUDLRULRRRDRDDLUDRDURDRDDUURDULRRULDLDLLUDRDDUDUULUDURDRLDURLRRDLDDLURUDRLDUURLLRLUDLLRLDDUDLLLRRRLDLUULLUDRUUDRLDUUUDUURLRDDDDRRDRLDDRDLUDRULDDDRDUULLUUUUULDULRLLLRLLDULRDUDDRDDLRRLRDDULLDURRRURDDUDUDDRLURRLUUUULLDRDULUUDRDULDLLUDLURDLLURRDLUULURRULRLURRRRRUURDDURLRLLDDLRRDUUURDRDUDRDDDLLDDRDRRRLURRDUULULULULRRURDDLDDLLLRUDDDDDDLLLRDULURULLRLRDRR\n"
                    + "DDRLLLDLRRURRDLDDRUURRURRLRRRRUURUURDLURRRDDLRUDRURLUURLLRRLRLURLURURDULLLLDLRURULUUDURRLULRDRDRRDDLLULRLUDLUUUDRLLRRURRLDULDDLRRLUUUUDDLRLDRLRRDRDLDDURDDRDDLDLURLRRRDDUDLLRLRLURRRRULLULLLLDRLDULDLLDULRLDRDLDDRRDDDDRUDRLLURULRLDDLLRRURURDDRLLLULLULDDRDLDDDLRLLDRLDRUURRULURDDRLULLDUURRULURUUDULLRUDDRRLLDLLRDRUDDDDLLLDDDLLUUUULLDUUURULRUUDUUUDDLDURLDRDRRLLUDULDLUDRLLLDRRRULUUDDURUDRLUDDRRLLDUDUURDDRURLUURDURURURRUUDUDDLLLDRRRURURRURDLRULLDUDRLRLLRUDRUDLR\n"
                    + "RRRDRLRURLRRLUURDRLDUURURLRDRRUDLLUUDURULLUURDLLDRRLURRUDUUDRRURLRRDULLDDLRRRUDUUDUUDLDDDLUUDLDULDDULLDUUUUDDUUDUDULLDDURRDLRRUDUDLRDUULDULRURRRLDLLURUDLDDDRRLRDURDLRRLLLRUDLUDRLLLRLLRRURUDLUDURLDRLRUDLRUULDRULLRLDRDRRLDDDURRRUDDDUDRRDRLDDRDRLLRLLRDLRDUDURURRLLULRDRLRDDRUULRDDRLULDLULURDLRUDRRDDDLDULULRDDRUDRLRDDRLDRDDRRRDUURDRLLDDUULRLLLULLDRDUDRRLUUURLDULUUURULLRLUDLDDLRRDLLRDDLRDRUUDURDDLLLDUUULUUDLULDUDULDRLRUDDURLDDRRRDLURRLLRRRUDDLDDRURDUULRUURDRRURURRRUUDUDULUDLUDLLLUUUULRLLRRRRDUDRRDRUDURLUDDLDRDLDDRULLRRULDURUL\n"
                    + "DLLLRDDURDULRRLULURRDULDLUDLURDDURRLLRRLLULRDLDRDULRLLRDRUUULURRRLLRLDDDRDRRULDRRLLLLDLUULRRRURDDRULLULDDDLULRLRRRUDRURULUDDRULDUDRLDRRLURULRUULLLRUURDURLLULUURUULUUDLUDLRRULLLRRLRURDRRURDRULRURRUDUDDDRDDULDLURUDRDURLDLDLUDURLLRUULLURLDDDURDULRLUUUDLLRRLLUURRDUUDUUDUURURDRRRRRRRRRUDULDLULURUDUURDDULDUDDRDDRDRLRUUUUDLDLRDUURRLRUUDDDDURLRRULURDUUDLUUDUUURUUDRURDRDDDDULRLLRURLRLRDDLRUULLULULRRURURDDUULRDRRDRDLRDRRLDUDDULLDRUDDRRRD"


    doMySolution input

    printfn "END"
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

Answer (score 2):

That was a fun exercise. Sorry if this isn't much help, but I'll post my approach here, since it at least has the advantage of being contrasting. It's late afternoon, and I didn't feel like thinking, so I thought I'd let the type system do the work.

In order to do that, I first defined these types:

```
type Instruction = Up | Down | Left | Right

type Key = One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine
```

The reason for that is that I could now define a function with the type `Key -> Instruction -> Key` using pattern matching without having to think hard about the problem. Not only that, but I get compile-time checking that I've handled all possible combinations:

```
// Key -> Instruction -> Key
let nextKey current instruction =
    match current, instruction with
    | One, Up      -> One
    | One, Down    -> Four
    | One, Left    -> One
    | One, Right   -> Two
    | Two, Up      -> Two
    | Two, Down    -> Five
    | Two, Left    -> One
    | Two, Right   -> Three
    | Three, Up    -> Three
    | Three, Down  -> Six
    | Three, Left  -> Two
    | Three, Right -> Three
    | Four, Up     -> One
    | Four, Down   -> Seven
    | Four, Left   -> Four
    | Four, Right  -> Five
    | Five, Up     -> Two
    | Five, Down   -> Eight
    | Five, Left   -> Four
    | Five, Right  -> Six
    | Six, Up      -> Three
    | Six, Down    -> Nine
    | Six, Left    -> Five
    | Six, Right   -> Six
    | Seven, Up    -> Four
    | Seven, Down  -> Seven
    | Seven, Left  -> Seven
    | Seven, Right -> Eight
    | Eight, Up    -> Five
    | Eight, Down  -> Eight
    | Eight, Left  -> Seven
    | Eight, Right -> Nine
    | Nine, Up     -> Six
    | Nine, Down   -> Nine
    | Nine, Left   -> Eight
    | Nine, Right  -> Nine
```

Okay, so it's a little verbose, but it was trivial to write. It also included the benefit that I got to write `Seven, Up` as part of a regular piece of code ;)

Assuming that I'm going to read in my instructions text file and split it on newlines, I'll first write a function that finds the ultimate key by following the instructions from a previous key:

```
// Key -> seq<Instruction> -> Key
let follow startValue = Seq.fold nextKey startValue
```

This is simply a left fold over a sequence of `Instruction` values, using `nextKey` as the aggregator.

Likewise, you can `scan` an array of lines using the `follow` function:

```
// #seq<Instruction> [] -> Key []
let followAll instructions = instructions |> Array.scan follow Five |> Array.tail
```

This functions takes an array of `Instruction` sequences (one for each line), and `scan`s it using the `follow` function for each line, using `Five` as the initial seed.

Since `Array.scan` also returns the initial state (`Five`), the function only returns the tail.

Finally, you'll need to parse the input string:

```
// char -> Instruction
let parseChar = function
    | 'U' -> Up
    | 'D' -> Down
    | 'L' -> Left
    | 'R' -> Right
    | c   -> invalidArg "arg1" (sprintf "Unexpected character: %c." c)

// string -> seq<Instruction> []    
let parse (s : string) =
    let lines = s.Split [|'\n'|]
    Array.map (Seq.map parseChar) lines
```

The `parseChar` function throws an exception if the character isn't one of `'U'`, `'D'`, `'L'`, or `'R'`. It'd be more functional to return either a Maybe (`option`) or an Either value, but for a single-use script I thought this was okay.

You can now take your input string and compose it with `parse` and `followAll`, like this:

```
input |> parse |> followAll
```

This expression returns an array of `Key` values. I'll leave it as an exercise to translate back to a string of numbers, if that's required.

Comment: That solution is definitely concise & readable except for the huge match. The challenge also had a 'part 2' where you take on a keypad with a completely different scheme (diamond shaped) so it would be a bit tedious to have to re-write the match that whenever the keypad changes. Though I have to admit that's a pretty impressive usage of the type system.

Comment: @Biarity Quite the opposite, I found the second part trivial to solve exactly due to the fast that I solved the first part similar to what Mark did. You just make a different match function, and all the rest still holds. If you needed to solve it for arbitrary field form, it will be relatively straightforward to replace manual match by a data structure with links between cells.